# The best way to stop/cancel promise cascade in dart

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart, promise

I working with one complex logic and i needed to stop it if the client want to cancel the operation, but i'm lost about how to do it in dart

I have this:

```dart
final steps =  authenticate(login, password)
        .then((_) => checkLicence())
        .then((_) => registerDevice())
        .then((_) => createDatabaseOnServer())
        .then((_) => waitForDatabase())
        .then((_) => downloadDatabase())
        .then((_) => notifyDatabaseDownloaded())
```

And i want to add the stop/cancel option.

I think that the easier way is to add one global **bool cancelStep** and add it in all functions, like `if(cancelStep) throw CancelStepException(stepName)` and treat if i have to do an rollback, logout, etc. but i wan to know if the are other way to do it.

I sow CancelableOperation like an option, but i will have to keep the currentStep if i want to make some rollback logic.

Comment: As you may well need a specific rollback scenario for each step, I would just stick with what you had in mind (`if (cancelStep) throw...`). If you use a generic cancellation (one suits all), you will still have to split up your logic depending on what the last successful step was, so you might as well do it on the spot.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about Dart, but with JS & Promise extension lib ([c-promise2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/c-promise2)) you can do the following ([Live demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-fast-1vojr?file=/src/index.js)):

```
import CPromise from "c-promise2";

let i = 0;

const dummyStage = () => {
  let index = i++;
  return () => {
    console.log(`Stage[${index}]`);
    return CPromise.delay(1000);
  };
};

const authenticate = dummyStage();
const checkLicence = dummyStage();
const registerDevice = dummyStage();
const createDatabaseOnServer = dummyStage();
const waitForDatabase = dummyStage();
const downloadDatabase = dummyStage();
const notifyDatabaseDownloaded = dummyStage();

const steps = CPromise.resolve(authenticate("login", "password"))
  .then((_) => checkLicence())
  .then((_) => registerDevice())
  .then((_) => createDatabaseOnServer())
  .then((_) => waitForDatabase())
  .then((_) => downloadDatabase())
  .then((_) => notifyDatabaseDownloaded())
  .then(
    (v) => console.log(`Done: ${v}`),
    (e) => console.warn(`Fail: ${e} at ${e.scope}`)
  );

setTimeout(() => steps.cancel(), 4000);
```

The same thing with generators ([Live Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/stage-cancel-generator-nhtpp?file=/src/index.js)):

```
const steps = CPromise.from(function* () {
  try {
    yield authenticate("login", "password");
    yield checkLicence();
    yield registerDevice();
    yield createDatabaseOnServer();
    yield waitForDatabase();
    yield downloadDatabase();
    yield notifyDatabaseDownloaded();
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("isCanceledError", CPromise.isCanceledError(e));
    console.warn(`Fail: ${e} at ${e.scope}`);
  }
}).then((v) => console.log(`Done: ${v}`));

setTimeout(() => steps.cancel(), 4000);
```